# slow and unreliable wifi connection on HP 15 Touchsmart laptop

Tags: wireless, 14.10

I am running Lubuntu 14.10 Utopic on HP 15 Touchsmart laptop. It is installed alongside Windows 8 on the same machine.

While on Windows my wi-fi connection works just fine,on Lubuntu it is very slow (noticeably slower than on Windows) and it disconnects often.

I am looking for expert help with resolving this issue. I have no idea what to look for.

```
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
09:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the wireless channel which would helps you to get some good wireless speed

List the wireless extension with the command

```
iwconfig
```

Set your wireless channel in the router to 1 or 11 and save the router configuration and reboot it.

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel #
```

**#- Wireless channel number**

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. would you explain why I need to do it and what it would accomplish? What is a channel? What is a router? I thought that the router is the modem that my ISP gave me. No? Sorry about so much ignorance in this subject...